# Objective C get html from URL, encoding wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, encoding

I want to ge the html content from the url bellow:

```
https://bbs.sjtu.edu.cn/file/bbs/mobile/top100.html
```

The code I have use below:

```
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bbs.sjtu.edu.cn/file/bbs/mobile/top100.html"];
NSString *res = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url2 encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000) error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",res);
```

the result is null.
I have also tried with UTF8 encoding (also null) and ASCII encoding (has content and the english part of the content is right, but for Chinese charset, the content is garbled).

any one can help about this problem? I have been stuck here for a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) instead:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url2
                                                 usedEncoding:&encoding 
                                                        error:&error];
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still get null in the output.the error message I got from the error is `couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of its contents can’t be determined.`